# My many to many sequelize association builder method seems to overwrite the previously stored value, as if its a one to one relationship

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

This is my first time trying to make a Many to Many relationship in Sequelize, and it's going OK but I have one point of failure detected so far.

My goal is to establish a Profile as having many Housings, and a Housing as having many Profiles. My expectation is that the following code stores three separate premade Housing entries in association with a Profile. My actual result is that, after storing all three (supposedly), I retrieve "all three" and just get one.

I've tried:

(1) Investigating the relationship between the two tables. [It's correct.](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/)  Ctrl + F "User.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: User_Profile });" and you'll see what I mean when you compare that code to my code.

(2) Changing the `include` value in my `testGetAllHousings` methods. I originally suspected that perhaps it should be `include: Housing` but no, that throws an error that tells me it has to be `include: "housings"` because I specify that name with "as" keyword in this line: `Profile.belongsToMany(Housing, { through: "Profile_Housings", foreignKey: "profileId", as: "housings" });`

Were it not for (2), I might think that `profile.getHousings();` is set up incorrectly, but that's not the problem, because if it was, the code in (2) would retrieve all stored entries. But it retrieves 1 entry, hence the problem must be how it is being stored.

(3) Instead of `await newProfile.addHousing(housing);` which you'll see below, I've tried: `await newProfile.addHousings([housing])` which also failed. (in the identical manner!)

I'm certain now by the code you see below that the problem is in storing the associations.

I think this code is enough to explain the problem:

```js
const ipForTestOne = "111.111.111.111";

const created = await profileDAO.createProfileByIp(ipForTestOne);
expect(created.profileId).toBeDefined(); // passes

// this logs " 44 dog street 33 cats street 22 bird street 145rm", 
// which is 3 separate addresses
 console.log(housingForTestOne.address, housingForTestTwo.address, housingForBothTests.address, "145rm");
await profileDAO.recordPublicPickHousing(ipForTestOne, housingForTestOne);
const temp1 = await profileDAO.testGetAllHousings(created.profileId);
await profileDAO.recordPublicPickHousing(ipForTestOne, housingForTestTwo);
const temp2 = await profileDAO.testGetAllHousings(created.profileId);
await profileDAO.recordPublicPickHousing(ipForTestOne, housingForBothTests);
const temp3 = await profileDAO.testGetAllHousings(created.profileId);
if (temp1 === null || temp2 === null || temp3 === null) throw Error("hats");
console.log(temp1.housings ? temp1.housings[0].address : null, "146rm");
console.log(temp2.housings ? temp2.housings[0].address : null, "149rm");
console.log(temp3.housings ? temp3.housings[0].address : null, "152rm");
```

The final 3 console logs log the same address! `44 dog street`

Here are the methods I defined in the profileDAO:

```js
public async recordPublicPickHousing(ipAddress: string, housing: Housing): Promise<Profile> {
        const profiles = await Profile.findAll({ where: { ipAddress } });
        const noProfilesFound = profiles.length === 0;
        // if ip addr is new, create a profile;
        if (noProfilesFound) {
            const newProfile = await Profile.create({ ipAddress });
           // it definitely "adds" the correct housing unit, but adding overwrites prev value
            await newProfile.addHousing(housing);
            await newProfile.save();
            return newProfile;
        } else {
            // if ip addr is previously seen, update their housing ids
            const profile = profiles[0];
           // it definitely "adds" the correct housing unit, but adding overwrites prev value
            await profile.addHousing(housing);
            await profile.save();
            return profile;
        }
    }

public async testGetAllHousings(profileId: number): Promise<Profile | null> {
    return await Profile.findOne({ where: { profileId }, include: "housings" });
}
```

In my Profile model, I have the mixins set up:

```js
    declare getHousings: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Housing>;
    declare addHousing: HasManyAddAssociationMixin<Housing, number>;
    declare addHousings: HasManyAddAssociationsMixin<Housing, number>;
```

Not sure what's wrong, `addHousing` *should* create a list!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

Previously I had written

```js
Profile.belongsToMany(Housing, { through: "Profile_Housings", foreignKey: "profileId", as: "housings" });
Housing.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: "Profile_Housings", foreignKey: "profileId", as: "profile" });
```

I removed the `foreignKey: "profileId"` part from both and it worked. The clue is that if something is `through: "joinTableName"` it doesn't also need a `foreignKey`; Sequelize will take care of it.